# Debian with Ubuntu's lucid lynx theme?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, themes, skin

Is it possible to use the new Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx theme with Debian Lenny 5.0? Is there a "skin" or something that is available? If not, is it possible to "export" Ubuntu's config to a Debian installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Ambience and Radiance over there: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/light-themes

Comment: Thanks for the link. Knowing the theme name I could search it in gnome-look after this post: http://www.funzt.info/?p=474. http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance_R+(Ambiance+Right+Side)?content=123927